# /bin/sh invoked from make doesn't find command with unquoted dash-argument

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have a makefile to build some transducers using Xerox' finite state tools (xfst in this case), which I invoke in my makefile like so (except with a hard tab instead of spaces in the actual makefile, of course):

```
latin.fst: nouns.fst verbs.fst
    xfst -f build/latin.fst.build
```

On my laptop (a Mac with OS X 10.6.2) this works just fine, but on my university's Linux machines I get this error:

```
make: xfst: Command not found
make: *** [nouns.fst] Error 127
```

After some debugging I've found two ways to fix this problem. The first is to quote the `-f` argument to xfst: `"-f"`, the other is to say `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of the makefile.

From the second fix (and how make works) it looks like the problem is with how /bin/sh executes the command. Now, /bin/sh is linked to /bin/bash, so it's not because of some kind of weird shell being installed as /bin/sh. Also, invoking /bin/sh and running the commands, or invoking `/bin/sh -c "xfst -f build/latin.fst.build"` works just dandy.

Make is GNU Make 3.81, bash is GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

This a weird error and I don't know what's causing it, but here's what I'd try:

```
.PHONY: experiment
experiment:
    @echo make's SHELL variable: $(SHELL)
    @echo the actual shell: $$SHELL
    which xfst
```

**Edit:**
Wait a second... the error message says that Make failed while trying to make nouns.fst, not latin.fst. Is that right? (If it is, then this problem just got weirder.)

**EDIT:**
All right, now I'm clutching at straws. I'd broaden the search, try running other programs that take options, try aliasing "xfst -f", try making a local symbolic link to xfst, try enclosing the whole command in quotes or backticks... and then just admit that I was totally stumped.

Comment: Good suggestions. Here's the output I get (after removing the genitive quote that made sh cry =):

    makes SHELL variable: /bin/sh
    the actual shell: /local/gnu/bin/bash
    which xfst
    /uio/arkimedes/s11/arnskj/sw/bin/xfst

Invoking /local/gnu/bin/bash as a shell and executing `xfst -f build/latin.fst.build` works just fine. Same for `/local/gnu/bin/bash -c 'xfst -f build/latin.fst.build'`

Comment: Er, right. I messed up the formatting of the output from `make experiment`. $(SHELL) is `/bin/sh`, the actual shell i `/local/gnu/bin/bash`, and which finds the correct path to xfst.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the weird error. nouns.fst is made in the same way that latin.fst, just with a different build file. There are several FSTs that are built in the same way (and fail in the same way). For simplicity's sake I just listed one of the rules and forgot to mention that there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you modified a `bash`-specific startup file (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`) to change your `$PATH` on the Linux machines to include the directory where `xfst` is located.  In that case, running under `/bin/sh` would not invoke `.bash*` so the correct directory would not be on your path.

Comment: I have customized my path. But if I add `env` as a command before the offending one, PATH does contain all the values I want. Also, if it's dependent on PATH, why does quoting the -f argument fix it?

Comment: Odd.  Perhaps you could try `make -d` on both machines to see what's going on under the covers.

Comment: Unfortunately `make -d` doesn't really say how the shell invoked. Basically, it just says "I'm gonna execute the command `xfst -f build/latin.fst.build' now", but no specifics about how it goes about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you move between systems that use different line endings, it's always a good idea to check whether that's a culprit in problems you encounter. As I'm sure you know, Linux and Unix use `0x0a`, DOS and Windows use `0x0d 0x0a` and Macs use `0x0d`. Try looking at the file with 
`hd filename` to see what style line endings you have (they may even vary within the file).

Comment: How does line endings explain that quoting fixes the problem? Besides OS X is UNIX these days, so the file has 0x0a line endings (I checked).